# How to re-add a computer to domain without local admin password?

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, windows-server-2012

How to rejoin a system to domain which is out of domain and i don't have Local

admin password ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Nope.  It cannot be done.  However, that doesn't mean that you're in trouble.

Joining a computer to a domain causes significant changes to the security implementation that the computer is using.  Not only will joining the domain allow you to log in using domain accounts, but the computer joining the domain agrees to receive details from the domain controller, such as Group Policy updates.  It does make sense that such a significant change is something that non-administrators should not be able to alter.

The good news is that there are multiple ways to become an administrator.

The less official way is to use chntpw which is a program in Linux.  I've done that a few times rather easily by downloading the latest copy of a disc image from systemrescuecd.org

- I've had this work well several times, although some computers would not boot nicely in a straightforward way, which I fixed by passing the following parameters to the Linux kernel: `noapic nolapic` (that's a lowercase L in the second parameter).  Once booted up nicely, the experience is menu based and I've found it works sufficiently easily and well if you carefully read the instructions shown on the screen.  This is coming from someone who has experience having IT students do this in my classroom.

The more official way is to boot off of a Windows installation media.  In recent versions, pressing Shift-F10 on an early screen (like the first or second screen) will initiate a hidden option of presenting you with a command prompt.  Bam!  You are now in a Windows environment, and so the boot device (the installation disc) provides you with Administrative access.

Unfortunately, an attempt to create a local user will then affect the copy of Windows that booted (which is a temporary environment created when booting off the media), and you will want to change the more permanent installation on the computer.  A workaround for Windows 10 is described by https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/reset-windows-10-password-with-boot-cd.html

Basically, the steps are:

- determine what drive letter your long-term Windows operating system is on.  That may be different than what you are used to.  (The drive letters may change when booted from the installation disc.)
- Change to that drive by typing the drive letter, a colon, and pressing Enter.  For instance, if the drive is named C:, then at the command prompt run:
  `C:`
- run: `copy \Windows\System32\utilman.exe \Windows\System32\utilman.exe.bak`
- ensure that worked well.  If not, consider getting help from an expert to figure out what happened.
- run: `copy \Windows\System32\cmd.exe \Windows\System32\utilman.exe`
- Reboot to the normal Windows installation.  (Having started the Windows installation media, you can run `weputil reboot` if you like.)
- Click on the Accessibility icon (somewhat resembling a common logo of a person in a wheelchair)
- That will utilman.exe which is now the copy of cmd.exe that you made
- Optional: create a new user.  e.g., `net user`*`customUserName`*`/ADD`
- Change the password for a user.  e.g., `net user`*`customUserName`*`*`

  - The referenced website suggests putting the desired password on the prompt, instead of an asterisk.  That can be done, but I consider that to not be the safest habit to develop.  Instead, the asterisk will cause the program to prompt you from the password.  No bullet points, nor other indicators, will show how many keys you press as you invisibly type the password.
- Ensure that user is a local Administrator: `net localgroup Administrators`*`customUserName`*`/ADD`
- Offhand (I'm not testing these instructions as I note them), I don't think rebooting will be needed there, but if you still can't log in, reboot.  (`shutdown /r`)
- After you are logged in as the new user, and you can become an Administrator, and so you know things are working, proper procedure would be to fix the damage you've done:

  - run: `copy %SystemRoot%\System32\utilman.exe.bak %SystemRoot%\System32\utilman.exe`

Once you have a local account which is an administrator, then you should be able to join the domain (presuming, of course, that other standard requirements are met, such as a an existing domain controller functioning well, that the version of Windows is not a "home edition", that you have a password for an account on the domain that has enough administrative access to let computers join the domain).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the local admin password you have reinstall the server, that's the official Microsoft statement. But you can use use [ERD Commander](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460909.aspx) to reset the local administrator password and then join it to the domain.

1. Create a disc with ERD Commander ISO
2. Boot the computer with this disc
3. It will show you a desktop. You can access the LockSmith Tool under Start >> Programs
4. From there you can change the password

Hope this helps.

Comment: Despite the windows-server-2012 tag, I'm thinking that tag simply meant the domain controller is using that, not necessarily that the person is trying to join a server to the domain.  When the answer says "you have [to] reinstall the server", that makes it sound like the domain controller needs to be re-installed, which is certainly not the case just to be able to get a workstation joined to the domain.  (Granted, re-installing the operating system on the workstation would be one way to work around the problem, which is the approach I believe you were conveying.)